# Can I get the path of the currently running java executable?

Tags: java, command-line, system-properties

Suppose I want to run a java program from the command line and I use this command:

```
myExes\java\java.exe AJavaProgram
```

As you can see, java.exe is not in my path, so I am running it manually rather than simply using the command `java AJavaProgram`.

I would like the program to return/print the first entry in the command, in this case, that entry is `myExes\java`. (Including java.exe at the end of this is also fine).

Is there a way to do this?

Initially, I thought it would be simple. args[0] would return the path, but that is not the case.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please feel free to visit the [help] to familiarize yourself with the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ProcessHandle.current()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#current%28%29) returns the current Java process.  You can use that to see the full command in the process handle’s info:

```
ProcessHandle.current().info().command().ifPresent(
    cmd -> System.out.println(cmd));
```

Comment: This one is best because it manages to give the full command. Although this relies on newer versions of Java. Andreas also had a good answer, but missed java.exe and wasn't quite as precise. Thanks VGR

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the string `"myExes\java\java.exe"`, but you can get the location of the Java installation.

The following are results for running with OpenJDK 14 on Windows 10:

```java
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.boot.library.path"));
```

*Output*

```
C:\prog\Java64\jdk-14
C:\prog\Java64\jdk-14\bin
```

For reference, the full path of `java.exe` is:

```
C:\prog\Java64\jdk-14\bin\java.exe
```

Comment: If I just copy and paste the JDK to a new folder and run java from there, this reports the new location rather than the original. So this answer is also fine, it would work for what I need, but VGR was slightly more precise so I had to go with his. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderPorter If you think this is a *useful* answer, then you should up-vote it. You can *up-vote* more than one useful answer, but you can only *accept* one answer, i.e. the one that *best* answers your question.

Comment: I am a new user so you might not actually see the change since I don't have enough reputation myself to have visible upvotes. But it has been done.

Answer (score -2):

How about this way?
You can get a java home dir.

```java
String path = System.getProperty("java.home");
```

Answer (score -2):

When you do `myExes\java\java.exe AJavaProgram` `AJavaProgram` is the arg to `java.exe` and not the reverse. Its the same when you do `java AJavaProgram`, `AJavaProgram` is the arg to `java`.