# Get absolute path to Java in Java programs

Tags: java

I need to use `ProcessBuilder` to invoke `java -jar another-program.jar` in a Java program. When Java is not in `$PATH` I will need to find the location of current running Java process, otherwise `ProcessBuilder` will throw `IOException`.

One working solution is this:

```
String javaPath = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java";
```

But when I run the Java program with JDK, it will return the Java binary inside the JRE folder instead.

How can I retrieve the correct Java path?

I don't want to rely on `JAVA_HOME` or `/proc/self/exe`, hopefully there's a pure Java solution.

Comment: If running the other app using the "java -jar" and invoking `main()` is not necessary then maybe this would be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9509608/5872703

Comment: Why can't you use the java binary inside the JRE folder? It works the same as the other one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62077059/10871900 might help.